# Android call method from another app

Tags: android, methods, static, package

I have 2 android apps. Both are installed on the phone. Lets say the package name for the two are com.android.test1 and com.android.test2.  How can i call the method `Main2method()` from the test1.Main class ?

Class for test1:

```
package com.android.test1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Class for test2:

```
package com.android.test2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main2 extends Activity {  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public static void Main2method() {
        //do something..
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to create ActionReceiver class in test1 (app1) also?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you can broadcast an Intent to call it.

```
Intent it = new Intent("com.android.test2.Main2method");
context.sendBroadcast(it)
```

Make a `BroadcastReceiver` in `com.android.test2.Main2` to receive the broadcast:

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("com.android.test2.Main2method".equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
            Main2method();
        } 
    }
}
```

Register the receiver in `onCreate` method of class `Main1`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    receiver = new ActionReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.android.test2.Main2method");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Question: Do I have to have the ActionReceiver Class in both apps ?

Comment: How to call ` Main2method();` from class Main2 in test2 app in another class ActionReceiver normally it does not recognize it?

Comment: Need to create ActionReceiver class in test1 (app1) also?

Answer (score 3):

in order to call method between different application you will need to use, [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

also you will need [intent-filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) 
 and [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send callbacks from app1 to app2:

1. you should throw your own `Intent` with data from app1. (take look at `PendingIntent`).
2. into yout app2 you should register `BroadcastReceiver` which will handle your app1's `Intents`.
3. broadcastreceiver's  `onReceive` method (in app2) will be called each time when your Intent will be thrown by app1 and catched by app2. (put your logics there)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call a method of one app from another app.
Instead, you have to invoke one activity from another and fetch result using Intent filters.

These links might help you

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

Answer (score 0):

Register the receiver in onCreate method of class Main1: is not correct, instead you must register in onCreate method of class Main2

Comment: This answer appears to be a comment on another answer. However you have also made a statement on how to fix the issue. Both without any expansion or explanation. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76177780/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).