# Get window (current task) title

Tags: android, android-activity

I am currently using this code to retrieve process name:

```
 List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
     if(taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxxxxx") != true){

        ////com.xxx.xxx

     }
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the active 'window' title, for example, when I open a web browser the title is "www.google.com" and if I open a conversation with Mister X in SMS/MMS, the current title is "Mister X 0245478767".

Answer (score -1):

Activity class has method [getTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getTitle%28%29) that might give what you are looking for. I just don't know how to use it through ActivityManager or is it even possible to call it from another app.

Comment: I guess you don't have any control of those other apps, so [Broadcasts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12339345/262462) are not useful either