# Android call method from another app without starting it

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two android applications with different packages `App1` and `App2`. Suppose I want to call a method `Method1` written in `App1`, from `App2`. One solution I found in the following link, [Android call method from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339083/android-call-method-from-another-app), suggested that we should register a `BroadcastReceiver`  in `App1` and call `sendBroadcast()` from `App2`. But the problem is, I could call the `Method1` only if App1 is running in the background. Otherwise, nothing is happening.

How to resolve this issue? Are there any other ways to call `Method1` without having to start `App1`?

Comment: use a service plus aidl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the problem is, I could call the Method1 only if App1 is running in the background.

This is incorrect, if you register any component (`BroadcastReceiver`, `Service`, `Activity`, etc.) in the AndroidManifest.xml and it is exported, other applications can trigger it with an `Intent` regardless of the current state of the application process.

Perhaps the issue you are running into is that the example you linked to registers the `BroadcastReceiver` in Java code.  If you instead publish the `<receiver>` in your manifest, it will be externally accessible always.  This is explained in the [SDK Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Can we call a method defined in another activity without creating the instance of the activity? Because I have written the broadcast receiver in separate class file and when I am unable to trigger the method written in the Activity class.

Comment: If an `Activity` is what you want to launch, then launch the `Activity` directly from your `App2`, not a `BroadcastReceiver`...go straight to the source.  Call `startActivity()` with a proper `Intent` rather than `sendBroadcast()`.