# Call a specific app when rtsp:// link is clicked, without prompting the user to chose one?

Tags: android

I have a webview app that display a website that contains rtsp:// links which are live streaming videos.

When I click on one of the links, it asks the users what app they would like to use to open that link.

What is a fessible way to ignore this diag, and send the user straight to an player app called "vplayer" considering the user has already installed it?

I found that this would be the easiest way to play rstp:// streamings "in" my app without having to integrate the vitamio bundle in it and making a player from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intent with an app name, but if they don't have that app installed it will fail.  That's why we put up the chooser-  because we don't know what app the user is using.  The best way to get rid of the dialog is for the user to click the "Use Always" button.  Then they'll never see the dialog again.  Or if they don't want to set a default app they can hit the "Use Once" button and they're choosing to see the dialog again.

Answer (score 0):

call that specific app by using

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("Vplayer package name");
    startActivity(intent);
```

and pass **rstp link** to that app by accecing method in vplayer package using broadcast receiver [for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339083/android-call-method-from-another-app) before you starting intent.